# Class factory mixin

Tags: c++

I would like to create in a mixin `class` that would impart a `class` factory method for the final class of a concrete type through several layers of inheritance. More specifically, I would like to have the factory method produce a new instance of the actual object it is called as a member of.

So, class "factory" is inherited by class `A`, class `A` is inherited by class `B`, I would like to find a way to do `B::create()` and create an instance of `B`. As far as I can tell this precludes the use of a template taking the type in the class `A` since then `B::create()` would produce an instance of `A`.

Comment: Sorry, I think it was an accident as I changed "endowed" to "impart" (as I read over it again it seemed a little more correct)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe CRTP would do? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

```
template <typename T>
struct Mixin
{
    T * create() const { return new T; }
};

class Target : public Mixin<Target>
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: Though, you'd need to inherit from it on every level of the hierarchy.

Comment: +1. But this requires that B inherit from Mixin<B>. I think the ideal solution would work even with `class A : Mixin<A> {}; class B:A {};`

Comment: Aaron McDaid described what I am looking for, I don't want to force the inheritance of the mixin when implementing derivations of A or of B.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The code in the base class knows nothing about any of the derived classes, unless you specifically inject this kind of knowledge yourself, by means of a template parameter or otherwise. There's no way to do that automatically.